# JRuby/Resque how to reduce memory footprint

Tags: resque, jrubyonrails

I have a JRuby/Rails app with a worker queue which uses Resque/Redis. When I do

```
cat /proc/{pid}/status
```

for the {pid} of the Resque process, it yields a VmSize of 692 MBytes. My rake task (in $RAILS_ROOT/lib/tasks) which starts the Resque process looks like this:

```
require "resque/tasks"
task "resque:setup" => :environment
task "resque:work" => :environment do
    ENV['QUEUE']="*"
end
```

My Resque workers sit in $RAILS_ROOT/app/workers, and my models are in $RAILS_ROOT/app/models. Is there a way I can fire up Resque without the controllers, views, and all of the libraries they pull in? My workers only need access to the models and the APIs of other workers and a few gems.

Also, is there any other way to reduce VmSize of the Resque task?

Comment: would be valuable to know how you deploy using jruby e.g. what server are you using and how you spawn the worker, are you using jruby for the worker as well or not ?

Comment: I'm using JRuby for the worker. I deploy the main app in Tomcat, and then call the Resque worker from the WEB-INF/lib/tasks folder of my Rails app, using JRuby. 2 processes are created.

Comment: I'm willing to propose an answer of running things in a single process (as part of the Tomcat deployment) if you're willing to do so, if everything is thread-safe that should reduce your footprint a lot. how do you feel about running the resque worker in a separate Java thread as part of the application ?

Comment: I`m not so sure. It works now, so I`m reluctant. Also,  we may need to add more workers, so I`d like to perhaps switch to sidekiq.